# How to update customer information directly in the database

Tags: customer-account

I have several customers that I need to change a field in.  In my case, the account manager email address.  I'm trying to determine the best way to approach this.  I have enough that I don't want to have to go through the UI to do it as that would be time prohibitive.  It seems like making the changes directly in the database would be easiest but I can't figure out which table contains that information.

What is the best way to go about doing this?  If it is directly in the database, which table contains that data?

I'm using Magento Commerce v2.3.5

Comment: Is there any info in my answer that are cryptic or difficult to understand, apologies, I don’t know your background or level of expectations and my answer may need tuning

Comment: If you have a email as example that you know that iso been used it exists in database so you can do a search in the whole database for that email and see in which table it is and column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing data in the database directly has several inherent problems: it may leave orphans especially if you're only starting with Magento, it is prone to errors and it is not reusable.

For your customer problem, it may be quite simple fortunately, you may want to look in the backend `System/Import` and use the type 'customer main file' like the screenshot below

[image]

for general purpose of batching a change, I would recommend scripting, it is quite reasonably straight forward to write commands in Magento 2:

for instance, feel free to take a look at: https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/simpledescription/src/master/Command/ReadSimpleProductDescription.php which is a basic example on writing a command